# LaTeX template for math articles on arXiv

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, article, abstract, arxiv

I tried to write a LaTeX code for making something a document like [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610903.pdf) paper on arxiv (It is a paper by Terence Tao).

1. My try is given below but I want to include the table of contents too. I am actually including sections manually with specific fonts and hence they do not appear in the table of contents.
2. Also is there a way to change the margin for abstract that is little larger than the body of the article (as given in the paper with link [above](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610903.pdf)).

The code is as follows:-

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\bibTitle}[1]{``#1''}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\graphicspath{ {./downloads/} }

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hexsize{10pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheoremstyle{named}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3's }#1}
\theoremstyle{named}
\newtheorem*{namedtheorem}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{namedlemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\theoremstyle{conclusion}
\newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
\theoremstyle{observation}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}



\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\newcommand\nd{\textsuperscript{nd}\xspace}
\newcommand\rd{\textsuperscript{rd}\xspace}
\newcommand\nth{\textsuperscript{th}\xspace}
\newcommand\lref[1]{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
\setlength\parskip{0cm}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\HRulegrossa}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2mm}}

\newcommand{\C}{C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\W}{C^{\infty}(W,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\CC}{C_c^{\infty}(W,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\CCx}{C_c^{\infty}(W_x,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\CCy}{C_c^{\infty}(W_y,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Wx}{C^{\infty}(W_x,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\CCC}{C_c^{\infty}}
\newcommand{\CCCC}{C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Wa}{C_c^{\infty}(W_0,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Wb}{C_c^{\infty}(W_1,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Wc}{C_c^{\infty}(W_2,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Wd}{C_c^{\infty}(W_4,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Wxy}{C_c^{\infty}(W_x \cap W_y,\mathbb{C}^m)}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}^n}
\newcommand{\co}{\mathbb{C}^m}
\newcommand{\fo}{\widehat{f}(\xi)}
\newcommand{\fou}{\widehat{f}(\zeta)}
\newcommand{\D}{\Omega^{k}(M)}
\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inp}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1, #2}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} 
  {}                
  {0pt}            
  {\huge}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{13pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textsc{\textbf{ THE THEOREM}}
    \end{center}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\begin{center}
   \fontsize{12pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textsc{Himanshu Bimal}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{center}
   \fontsize{12pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textsc{Abstract}
\end{center}
In this document , we shall discuss some elementary results on bla bla bla... which to write the exact abstract is extended as bla bla bla...
\tableofcontents
\begin{center}
   \fontsize{12pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textsc{{1. Introduction}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: A sample from my try looks like this]

Comment: Have you tried using the [amsart, amsproc, and/or amsbook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) document classes?

Comment: @Mico, Can you please elaborate a bit on how it works,? I tried including it but doesn't help instantly. Probably,  something is incomplete. Thanks!

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: This helps to great extent, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to strongly recommend you employ the [amsart](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) document class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}

\title{Perelman's proof of the Poincaré conjecture:\\ 
A nonlinear PDE perspective}
\author{Terence Tao}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
We discuss some of the key ideas of Perelman's proof of  Poincaré's conjecture via the Hamilton program of using  the Ricci flow, from the perspective of the modern theory of nonlinear partial differential equations.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Perelman's theorem}

In three remarkable papers \dots

\begin{theorem}[Perelman's theorem, finite time extinction case]
Let \dots
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```